# How do I set permissions on IIS8 for AWSTATS

Tags: permissions, iis-8, awstats

System:

- Windows Server 2012 IIS8
- AWSTATS Version: 7.1.1

`awstats.domain.com.config` is created with these settings:

When I go to:
    http://awstats.domain.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?config=domain.com

The whole pages loads with no stats.  On the top it says this:

> Last Update: Never updated (See 'Build/Update' on awstats_setup.html page) Update Now (link)

I click the Update Now link which takes me to the next page where I am hit with this error:

> Error: Couldn't open server log file
>       "C:\HostingSpaces\domain.com\logs\W3SVC8\u_ex130520.log" : Permission denied

There are a number of log files, one for each day in this folder `W3SVC8`.

What do I have to do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

The IIS ApplicationPool used by your awstats site needs to be granted read permission on the logs directory.

If the ApplicationPool has an explicit user identity, then give this user read permissions on the logs directory.  If the ApplicationPool's identity is the default of *ApplicationPoolIdentity* then you can assign permissions directly to that ApplicationPool by entering `IIS APPPOOL\NameOfAppPool` when assigning security, for example `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`.